# SQLDataReader connection close

Tags: c#, database-connection, sqldatareader, stylecop

How to define rule in stylecop to force developer to close SQLDataReader() or connection?

if there exists any other solution then also please suggest.

The solution required is to force developer to close sqldatareader

or

we can do any other changes in DAL or any other apporach to make sure that connection of datareader is close..

Answer (score 0):

How about using a delegate?  I don't know your exact architecture, but we have wrapped the `ExecuteReader()` method in our own method, let's call it `ExecuteReaderWrapper()` that ensures the correct DB connection is used etc.  `ExecuteReaderWrapper()` basically just returns the `SqlDataReader` returned by `ExecuteReader()`.

Now we don't write any custom code using these methods (we use `DataSets` in stead), so we don't have the problem you do.  But one option would be to change `ExecuteReaderWrapper()` to expect a delegate in stead of returning the `SqlDataReader`.  Then `ExecuteReaderWrapper()` would pass the `SqlDataReader` to the delegate and to all the required cleanup afterwards.  Then the developers don't have to worry about closing at all.